# IIS Rewrite rule conditions is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

We are going to redirect a sites language to one information page during a transition period. This redirect rule have conditions in it that should be allowing some URLs to still be accessible.
These conditions do not work, and it is hard to find out why it seems like...

The url matching works, but conditions in the rewrite rule below does not work.
The conditions should allow the those urls and it's children to still be accessible.
We have used this site to create the patterns: https://www.regextester.com/

This is the rule that have been created that does not work:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect swedish site" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="sv(|\/.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="rapporter(|\/.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="media/pressmeddelanden(|\/.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />          
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

The below code resolved the issue

```
    <rule name="Redirect swedish branch rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^sv/(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/sv/rapporter/.*" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/sv/media/pressmeddelanden/.*" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and you will see what values are there for `REQUEST_URI` and whether you wrote the correct patterns. None of those test sites helps if you don't put IIS/HTTP context into consideration.

Comment: Please give an example of your needs, I will make demo for you.